# Ionic.Zip is super slow on windows 8

Tags: c#, io, windows-8.1, dotnetzip

I am using Ionic.Zip 1.9.1.8 ad I recently upgraded to windows 8.

In my application I use following command to unzip ad it was working fast and great on windows server 2012.

```
zipFile.ExtractAll(tempFileName);
```

In my windows 8 machine that has the same spec as the server it takes 3 to 4 times more to extract the file.

Does anybody have the same issue?

Comment: I think there is a setting to make it run on multiple threads. Try that. But if I see Ionic.Zip, I will run the other way. It has a nasty bug ( when the size of the file is a multiple of 128K, the parallel compression algorithm corrupts the file)

Comment: Cheeso appears to have lost interest in the project a while ago.  Time to move on perhaps, zip support is included in the .NET Framework today.